# Deserialize JSON with Numeric Rows

Tags: json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize some JSON into a list using JSON.NET; however, there is a number in the way:

Here is the JSON:

```
"payment_info": {
    "fb_id": "",
    "order_items": {
      "0": {
        "product_id": "4534",
        "type": "product",
        "shipping_cost_per_item": "1.00",
        "quantity": "3",
        "price_each": "10.00",
        "price_total": "30.00"
      }
    },
```

Here is my class:

```
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public string product_id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string shipping_cost_per_item { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public string price_each { get; set; }
        public string price_total { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderItems
    {
        public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I tell the converter to ignore the 0? There will be a 1,2,3 for each order item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues here.

First, your JSON is not valid; it appears to be only a fragment. Valid, complete JSON would look like the following.  (I added enclosing braces, removed the trailing comma and balanced the braces for the `payment_info` object.)

```
{
    "payment_info": {
        "fb_id": "",
        "order_items": {
            "0": {
                "product_id": "4534",
                "type": "product",
                "shipping_cost_per_item": "1.00",
                "quantity": "3",
                "price_each": "10.00",
                "price_total": "30.00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since your fragment is enclosed in an object, you will need a corresponding top-level class to deserialize into.  That class needs a `payment_info` property to hold what is now your `OrderItems` class.  (I would recommend renaming that class to `PaymentInfo` if possible to avoid confusion.)

Second, the `Items` property inside the `OrderItems` class does not match the JSON.  In the JSON it is named `order_items`.  Since they don't match, you will get a null value when you deserialize.  You either need to rename the property or use a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to specify the JSON property name.

Third, the `order_items` property in your JSON isn't a list; it is an object.  Therefore you will get an error if you try to deserialize it into a list (once you fix the property name).  The usual solution to deal with this situation is to use a `Dictionary<string, T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

Putting it all together, if you make your classes like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public PaymentInfo payment_info { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentInfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, OrderItem> order_items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string shipping_cost_per_item { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string price_each { get; set; }
    public string price_total { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like this:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach (OrderItem item in root.payment_info.order_items.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine("product id: " + item.product_id);
    Console.WriteLine("type: " + item.type);
    Console.WriteLine("shipping cost per item: " + item.shipping_cost_per_item);
    Console.WriteLine("quantity: " + item.quantity);
    Console.WriteLine("price per item: " + item.price_each);
    Console.WriteLine("total price: " + item.price_total);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0t8gX